# Hibernate InvalidMappingException cannot find an error in syntax

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

when i try to start my hibernate application i get an InvalidMappingException but i can't find any mistakes in syntax of the mapping file. Additional remarks:

- class and column names are spelled correctly
- the mapped table is a view
- the database system is DB2
- application worked with shown configuration before

The mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="media.definitions">

    <class name="Category" table="GET_CATEGORY" mutable="false">
        <id name="id" column="ID" type="integer">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="BEZEICHNUNG" type="string" />
        <set name="children" inverse="true" lazy="true">
            <key column="OBERKATEGORIE" type="integer" />
            <index column="INDEX"/>
            <one-to-many class="Category" />
        </set>
        <many-to-one name="parent" column="OBERKATEGORIE" class="Category" 
            not-null="false" cascade="all" />
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

the error:

```
     [java] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
     [java] Initial SessionFactory creation failed: org.hibernate.InvalidMapping
Exception: Could not parse mapping document from resource media/definitions/Cate
gory.hbm.xml
     [java] org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping docum
ent from resource media/definitions/Category.hbm.xml
     [java]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.jav
a:569)
     [java]     at media.mediadbimpl.MediaDbImpl.init(MediaDbImpl.java:103)
     [java]     at media.frontend.Media.<init>(Media.java:50)
     [java]     at media.frontend.Media.main(Media.java:156)
     [java] Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse ma
pping document from invalid mapping
     [java]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.
java:502)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.jav
a:566)
     [java]     ... 3 more
     [java] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumb
er: 49; Attribut "type" muss f³r Elementtyp "key" deklariert werden.
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.c
reateSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.e
rror(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.repo
rtError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.repo
rtError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.repo
rtError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.a
ddDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1253)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.h
andleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.e
mptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:763)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerI
mpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:356)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentSc
annerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImp
l.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerI
mpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentSc
annerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration
.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration
.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XM
LParser.java:141)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.
parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
     [java]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAX
Parser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
     [java]     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
     [java]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.
java:499)
     [java]     ... 4 more
     [java] Java Result: 1
```

the configuration is hardcoded:

```
    Configuration sessionConf = new Configuration()
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", prop.getProperty("driver"))
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", prop.getProperty("url"))
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", prop.getProperty("user"))
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", prop.getProperty("pw"))
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "1")
        .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", prop.getProperty("dialect"))
        .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update")
        .setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread")
        .setProperty("show_sql", "false")
        .addResource("media/definitions/Category.hbm.xml");
    sessionFactory = sessionConf.buildSessionFactory();
```

Why do i get this error?

Comment: post complete stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Is added to main post. Sorry i forgot that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per hibernate mapping DTD file - `[hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd][1]`, you have 2 issues in your mapping file.

- 1. you should not have `index` tag in your mapping file as you are using the collection type as `set`:

The DTD file says:

> Declares the type and column mapping for a collection index
>   (array or list index, or key of a map).

```
<index column="INDEX"/>
```

So index can be used only for Arrays, Lists and Maps, it cannot be used for Set

- 2. Using attribute `type` inside `key` tag is not valid.

As per DTD, a key tag can have only below list of attributes where `type` is not part of the list:

```
<!ELEMENT key (column*)>
    <!ATTLIST key column CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST key property-ref CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST key foreign-key CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST key on-delete (cascade|noaction) "noaction">
    <!ATTLIST key not-null (true|false) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST key update (true|false) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST key unique (true|false) #IMPLIED>
```

So to fix your issue, the mapping for `set` should be like this:

```
<set name="children" inverse="true" lazy="true">
   <key column="OBERKATEGORIE"/>
   <one-to-many class="Category" />
</set>
```